# How to batch download papers from a reference list without DOI?

Tags: citations, reference-managers, doi, meta-analysis

I'm looking to download some papers from a reference list in an Excel file which consisted of all the basic info about a paper (e.g., author, year, title, publication, etc.) but unfortunately not the DOI. I've looked into many methods for batch downloading papers, but they all require the DOI to work. I've also looked into searching for DOI using the title of the paper but to no avail, as all the programs I've came across does the reverse, i.e., use the DOI to retrieve the rest of the metadata. I would greatly appreciate any pointers anybody has.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the question is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can submit batches of references to get DOIs manually through through Crossref Simple Text Query - https://apps.crossref.org/SimpleTextQuery

Comment: Wow!  I just tested it and it worked on some really obscure stuff.  It did not work on old Soviet journal articles, presumably because they have no DOIs.

Comment: Thank you!!! This is a simple solution that worked well for me.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it consistently.  That is precisely why DOI was created: so that papers can be  reliably located by algorithms.

For subscription journals, batch downloads are normally forbidden under the contract.  This rule can be enforced by banning you from downloading.

Comment: It might be helpful if anyone knew how to do it 99% accurately, even if it's impossible to do it 100% accurately